# What does the "affine" parameter do in PyTorch nn.BatchNorm2d?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

What is the purpose of the `affine` argument and what does it do?

```
class DilConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_C, out_C, kernel_size, stride, padding, affine=True):
        super(DilConv, self).__init__()
        self.ops = nn.Sequential(
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Conv2d(in_C, in_C, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, 
                    padding=padding, dilation=2, groups=in_C, bias=False),
          nn.Conv2d(in_C, out_C, kernel_size=1, bias=False),
          nn.BatchNorm2d(out_C, affine=affine))
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.ops(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation page for [`BatchNorm2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html), you will read:

> `affine` – a boolean value that when set to `True`, this module has learnable affine parameters. Default: `True`

Checking the source code on the base class [`_NormBase`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ad87365e54e7b20b49ac23ee325f1da732655808/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py#L17), you will see parameters `weight` and `bias` are only [defined](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ad87365e54e7b20b49ac23ee325f1da732655808/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py#L47-L49) if the argument `affine` is set to `True`. These parameters correspond to gamma and beta in the documentation formulae.